# Find all matches from a subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

assume there is a `friends` table. there are 10 users in it. each user is friend with others except itself.

Like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | friend_id |
+---------+-----------+
|   1     |     2     |
+---------+-----------+
|   1     |     3     |
+---------+-----------+
|   1     |     4     |
+---------+-----------+
|   2     |     1     |
+---------+-----------+
|   2     |     3     |
+---------+-----------+
|   2     |     4     |
+---------+-----------+
|   3     |     1     |
+---------+-----------+
|   3     |     2     |
+---------+-----------+
|   3     |     4     |
+---------+-----------+ AND more ....
```

Now How can I get all Friends of #1 Friends... . (friends of friends of #1)

I tried this query:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_id = 1
```

And put them in a variable $IN.

```
SELECT friend_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_id IN ( '$IN' )
```

but this is not working as expected.

**EDITED**

if user #1 has 100 friends and every friends of him has 100 friends.
so it should return 9900 ids to me. but it returns 99 ids.

any help. thanks.

Comment: What exactly not working - you get errors or what>

Comment: How many 'levels' of friends should it return?

Comment: friends of my friends for example. 2 level it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT theirFriends.friend_id
FROM friends AS friendsOfOne
JOIN friends AS theirFriends ON friendsOfOne.friend_id = theirFriends.user_id
WHERE friendsOfOne.user_id = 1
```

In case you want to leave out `1` (in this case `1`) as a friend of a friend of `1`, try this:

```
SELECT theirFriends.friend_id
FROM friends AS friendsOfOne
JOIN friends AS theirFriends 
    ON friendsOfOne.friend_id = theirFriends.user_id
    AND theirFriends.friend_id != friendsOfOne.user_id
WHERE friendsOfOne.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Of course we should remove the `person in question` from the results.

Comment: @xpy: How do you mean? He is asking for friends of friends. In case One is a friend of his own friends, he would be returned. I think OP should specify this if he doesn't want to include One. Same for others that will be returned multiple times.

Comment: if 1 has friend 2, and then 2 has 1 as a friend also, then 1 will be returned as a friend of 1. I suppose you can't tell that someone is a friend with himself.

Comment: wow, this works very well. I had another query. in a 4 million record table. it took 5 seconds. but this query took 0.005 second. you saved my life !!!, but yes. someone can not be a friend of itself.

Comment: @xpy: no you're close. 1 would be returned as a friend of the friend of 1, which is correct? :)

Comment: @Pars: You're welcome. I've extended the answer a bit :)

Comment: `!=` and `<>` both work in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: @Aquillo, had a similar problem and found this in my search.  that's what I was looking for however, this only returns friends of friends... how can you tweak it to also return first level friends?

Comment: @php-b-grader It would be pretty easy in that case, you won't need the extra `JOIN`: `SELECT friends.friend_id FROM friends WHERE friends.user_id = 1`. Replace `1` accordingly with the person of whom you're trying to retreive the friends.

Answer (score 1):

$IN should be comma separated, and your query shouldn't have `'` around the $IN because it is a set of integers

```
SELECT friend_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_id IN ($IN)
```

Comment: not working . please see edited post. I think IN will exit if finds at least one matched id.

Comment: something like this : IN (2,3,4). it should return friends of each one of these ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `SELECT` into the `IN`

```
SELECT friend_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_id IN
    (SELECT friend_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_id = 1)
```

But with many rows, a `JOIN` would probably be the better solution, as suggested by [Aquillo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863182/1557526).

Comment: not working . please see edited post. I think IN will exit if finds at least one matched id